# Use django ORM with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, django, django-orm, python-multiprocessing

I have a Django ORM database (mysql or sqlite), and would like to process each row with a fairly computationally intensive operation. What I have right now is something like:

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(language='')
for e in entry:
    e.language = detect_language(e.text)
    e.save()
```

If the database was the bottleneck, I would use a transaction to speed it up. However, the `detect_language` function is what takes the most time. I could try to run the script multiple times in parallel, but that would introduce a race condition.

I think this could be done with `multiprocessing` using `Pool.map()` - the main process fetches the DB entries, the child processes run `detect_language`. I am not sure how to do it in detail, e.g. whether to save the entries in the child process or in the main process.

Is there anything to take care of when passing ORM objects between processes? Can you give a short example how to use the ORM with multiprocessing?

I've just tied it, and something like this seems to work fine. I am still wondering if there is any caveat here, or if this can be improved performance wise (e.g. batching the DB update):

```
def detect_and_save(obj):
    obj.language = detect_language(obj.text)
    obj.save()

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
    pool.map(detect_and_save, entries)
```

Comment: Is this operation being run online or offline (eg in a Celery task)?

Comment: Offline, i.e. in a script (`import myapp.wsgi`). Eventually I'll probably use something like Celery, but currently for testing I'm using the simplest thing that works.

Comment: im getting AppRegistryNotReady error because i'm accessing other models in the method

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to pass the full ORM objects - you can just pass the parameter your function needs and save its result to the ORM objects.
2. You could use [bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) (available from Django 2.2 or as a [3rd party library](https://pypi.org/project/django-bulk-update/)) to save in a single query.

```
texts = [e.text for e in entries]
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    languages = pool.map(detect_language, texts)
for e, l in zip(entries, languages):
    e.language = l
Entry.objects.bulk_update(entries, ['language'])
```